# Not hearing back after multiple rounds of technical interviews

Tags: job-offer, email, email-etiquette

I applied at a relatively small but well-known software company as a software engineer and I had 4 rounds of interviews. My last interview was on Dec 18th and today is Jan 12th. I am currently working full-time but I was interviewing at other places and I have 2 other written offers that are good, and I really need to choose one. Should I send them an email that I haven't heard back or it is OK not getting feedback after over 3 weeks and I should assume I was rejected? If I should send them an email what should I say?

Comment: Often if you're not hearing back, you are their second choice and they're negotiating with their first choice. They don't want to tell you 'no' incase their first choice falls through.

Comment: @gnat this one answers my question. Thank you

Comment: @JoeStrazzere I really like this company and I prefer them over the other two. It's not just salary always, it's matter of the job and technologies they use as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just send them an email and say that you have two other offers and that you really want to work with this company and could they beyso kind as to give you feedback on your application status, or failing that when they will be able to give you feedback.

Typically once you have more than one in-person meeting with a company (I guess a video conversation in post-covid times) they will always let you know how the interview went. It is common to be ghosted at any time before - (ok, less common to be ghosted after the phone screen, but still).